# Creating different focal depth images from Lytro IIlum

Tags: post-processing, light-field, lytro

I am trying to use the Lytro Power Tools developer package to create images at different focal depths. I have a Lytro Illum light field camera which outputs the image as an LFR file. I have Lytro Power Tools installed using [the manual](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/LytroPowerToolsBeta101UserManual.334506729.pdf).

Based on my current interpretation of the manual, I should be able to enter

```
lfptool raw -i image_file.LFR --focus FLOAT
```

into the command line. However, when I enter this, it ignores the focus command and just unpacks the LFR file into a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FLOAT` in your command represents the type of data that should follow the argument, a floating-point number. Just like `-i PATH` means `-i <the path to the image file>`, the `--focus` argument expects something like `--focus 0.786` or similar.

I have no idea what an actual useful value might look like as I have no idea about the specific thing you're trying to do and I have no idea how to use these specific tools. But I do use a lot of command line utilities in my day job.